# How do I mock a method making an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write some tests for my Angular application and I would like to mock a method so that I do not make an actual call to the server.

Here is my method inside of my grid.service.ts:

```
     loadAccountListPromise(id: string) {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
                .toPromise()
                .then(
                (data) => {
                    this.results = this.formatData(data.json());
                    resolve(this.results);
                },
                (msg) => {
                    reject(msg);

                }
                );
        });
        return promise;

    }
```

So far I have tried writing something like this following the official angular test guide.  In my grid.service.spec.ts I have:

```
it('loadAcountListPromise should return Promise', () => {

            let someHttp;

            spyOn(myInnergridService, 'loadAccountListPromise').and.callThrough();

            myInnergridService.loadAccountListPromise(someHttp).then(
                ( response ) => { expect( response ).toBe( jasmine.any(Promise) );
            });
        });
```

Here I am spying on the method but by calling `.callThough()` I am using the actual implementation and thus making a real AJAX call to the server.  I want to avoid this and fake the GET request for testing purposes.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the testbed :

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpModule],
    providers: [
      YourService,
      // ... Other services
      { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
    ]
  });
});
```

then, in every test (or in a beforeEach) :

```js
it('testing http calls ...', inject([YourService, XHRBackend], (service: YourService, http: MockBackend) => {
  let cnt: MockConnection;
  let response = { contenu: 'anything you want here' };
  http.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
    cnt = connection;
    // Response (CHOOSE ONE)
    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
      body: JSON.stringify(response)
    })));
    // Error (CHOOSE ONE)
    connection.mockError(new Error('error'));
  });

  let goodCall = (method, url) => {
    expect(cnt.request.method).toBe(method);
    expect(cnt.request.url.endsWith(url)).toBe(true);
  };

  service.method().subscribe(res => goodCall(RequestMethod.Get, 'params/search'));
}));
```

Feel free to ask if you don't understand !

Comment: Oh, and for the import of the keywords : `import { HttpModule, Http, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestOptions, Headers, XHRBackend, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
`

Comment: Second import (sorry, I make separate comments to make it clearer): `import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
`

Comment: thanks but this is a bit much all at once...when you call `.method` this is my `loadAccountListPromise()` method, correct.  What is `(RequestMethod.Get, 'params/search')`?  is `RequestMethod` also my method?  Also, how would I test for value type?  I guess my spec above no longer applies :(

Comment: `method()` is the method that makes the http call you want to test. `MyService` is ... Your service, you probably guessed that :D If you look, for the last part, I created a function just before calling the method, called `GoodCall` : it takes an HTTP method (GET, PUT ...) and an endpoint as parameters, and see if the method calls the correct endpoint with the correct method. Here, I test if `method` is making a `http.get` (`RequestMethod.Get`), on the endpoint ending with `params/search`. This is easier like that, because you can just call are your methods making http calls in the same test !

Comment: (If you didn't see, `RequestMethod` is an import from `@angular/http`)

Comment: Ok I see, I noticed you are calling .subscribe to my method, but it returns a Promise object.  Would `service.method().then(res => goodCall(RequestMethod.Get, 'params/search'));` work in this case?

Comment: No sorry, I copied it a bit fast (I'm not doing it from memory). You can replace it with a `then`, `subscribe` is for observables.

Comment: Yes that is what I assumed see above :) . I am going to try now.

Comment: Remember to change the method (`RequestMethod.Get`) and the endpoint to cope with your own method !

Comment: Wait, why would I change `RequestMethod.Get` that is the import right...what do you mean by 'endpoint', the url?

Comment: In your `loadAccountListPromise` you don't have to change the get method, but I told you could call all methods in the same test, so I reminded you to change it in case the methode changes, sorry :) and the endpoint is **the end of the url**, you can see in the GooCall function that I test if the url ends with it. This means if you call `http://www.myapp.com/api/user/12345`, you change `params/search`  with `user/12345`

Comment: Right, since `loadAccountListPromise` fires of a GET, got it.  As for the endpoint params/search, for `loadAccountListPromise` I only have the `baseUrl` so I guess in this case I would place the whole url there.

Comment: will do trying now.

Comment: I have not run the test but I am getting an error at `http.connections.subscribe(( connection: MockConnection) => {
                conn = connection;` of `[ts] Property 'connections' does not exist on http...` . Also for `response` i put let `response: { content: Object }`

Comment: Did you copy the whole `it` test I gave you, including the injections, or did you copy the code in the it, without the injections ?

Comment: Did you also made the 2 imports that I gave in the first two comments on my answer ?

Comment: Ok I just noticed, `inject` cannot be found.  Am I missing some dependency...I made sure I'm importing all of them.  Also, angular.mock.inject() seems to be an AngularJS method...

Comment: Trust me, it's Angular 2+. Did you import `inject` ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct way but I just added `http` and `service` as local variables since `inject` did not work even after I imported `Inject` from `@angular/core`

Comment: Because it's inject from @angular/testing :D sorry, this is common import, usually it's done with the CLI

Comment: Ok got it to pass.  However, I am still unclear if I am testing my actual method.  On the last line I call `service.loadAccountListPromise('string').then(res => successCall(RequestMethod.Get, 'params/search'));` .  It seems I am calling my method here, but I am not sure how to pass my url instead of `'params/search'`.  In the `goodCall()` method do I add that to the `endsWith(url)` param?

Comment: Well your method uses `this.baseUrl`, so you need to pass `service.baseUrl` as a parameter instead of params/search. But again, this is my way of doing this, feel free to delete the goodcall method and put all of your expects in the `then` !

Comment: Much appreciated, I will try to wrap my head around this.

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html) to help you understand how it works, good luvk !

Comment: During the course of my research I have found that all of this stuff looks to be deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests